# File encoding from English text to UTF-8

Tags: python

How to convert a Non-ISO extended-ASCII English text, with CRLF line terminators to utf-8 in Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending Jishiyu's Answer, you might use [uchardet](http://packages.debian.org/sid/utils/uchardet) to identify the char set. For example

```
iconv -f `uchardet a_strange_file.txt` -t UTF-8 -o the_output_file.txt a_strange_file.txt
```

Although this does not do the job in python.

Answer (score 0):

i think the linux command unix2dos、dos2unix、iconv will helpful。

such like

> iconv -f latin-1 -t UTF-8 latin.txt >utf8.txt

Comment: But i need a python package that automatically converts to the specified format.

Answer (score 0):

If you obtain a raw byte-stream for your input file, you can then `decode` it to `utf-8`. See [this blog post](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/30/the-bytesstr-dichotomy-in-python-3/) with some Python 3 examples.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have created an automated [conversion script](https://gist.github.com/Barlog951/69aceea68c38230c57d6658884e2349c) using the [enca](http://linux.die.net/man/1/enca) library, 
I use it on my NAS to convert subtitles to UTF-8 but it could be utilized for any automated conversion

Feel free to use :)

**EDIT:**

```
#!/bin/bash
LANGUAGE=czech
TO=utf8
CONVERT="enca -L $LANGUAGE -x $TO"

# Find and onvert
find ./ -type f -name "*.srt" | while read fn; do
  IS_TARGET=`enca "${fn}" | egrep -ow -m 1 'UTF-8|Unrecognized|KOI8-CS2|7bit ASCII|UCS-2|Macintosh Central European'`

    if [ "$IS_TARGET" != "UTF-8" ] &&
       [ "$IS_TARGET" != "UCS-2" ] &&
       [ "$IS_TARGET" != "Macintosh Central European" ] &&
       [ "$IS_TARGET" != "Unrecognized" ] &&
       [ "$IS_TARGET" != "7bit ASCII" ] &&
       [ "$IS_TARGET" != "KOI8-CS2" ]; then

        echo "${fn} ---- Will be converted!"
    # optional backup of original srt
        # cp "${fn}" "${fn}.bak"
        $CONVERT "${fn}"
    fi  

done
```

Comment: You should probably include the source code in your answer as opposed to just linking to it.