# How to extract data recursively on Linux?

Tags: python, linux, mongodb, unicode, utf-8

I'm attempting to work on a large dataset, however, the format structure of the data has been split up into hundreds of directories.

> data/:
>   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z
>
> data/0:
>   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  symbols  t  u  v  w  x  y  z
>
> data/1:
>   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  symbols  t  u  v  w  x  y  z
>
> data/2:
>   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  symbols  t  u  v  w  x  y  z
>
> data/3:
>   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  symbols  t  u  v  w  x  y  z
>
> data/4:
>   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  symbols  t  u  v  w  x  y  z
>
> data/5:
>   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  symbols  t  u  v  w  x  y  z
>
> data/6:
>   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  symbols  t  u  v  w  x  y  z
>
> data/7:
>   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  symbols  t  u  v  w  x  y  z
>
> data/8:
>   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  symbols  t  u  v  w  x  y  z
>
> data/9:
>   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  symbols  t  u  v  w  x  y  z
>
> data/a:
>   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  symbols  t  u  v  w  x  y  z

Furthermore, the file types are also completely random.

> 0:       UTF-8 Unicode text
>
> 1:       UTF-8 Unicode text
>
> 2:       UTF-8 Unicode text
>
> 3:       UTF-8 Unicode text
>
> 4:       UTF-8 Unicode text
>
> 5:       Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with LF, NEL line terminators
>
> 6:       UTF-8 Unicode text
>
> 7:       UTF-8 Unicode text
>
> 8:       UTF-8 Unicode text
>
> 9:       UTF-8 Unicode text
>
> a:       UTF-8 Unicode text
>
> ...
>
> z:       UTF-8 Unicode text

The files contain a `email:password` format.

How can I get all of the content into a JSON file, or CSV file?

I'm looking to import the data to MongoDB.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure someone will help you better than I can but if I can point you in right direction I will.

Have you tried making a perl script? Ie

```
    opendir(DIR, ".");
 @files = grep(/\.cnf$/,readdir(DIR));
 closedir(DIR);

 foreach $file (@files) {
    //shuv in a JSON file
}
```

Something like that?

Answer (score 0):

The question was tagged with python, so I would recommend `os.walk()` ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.walk)) for recursively reading files. Something like:

```
# path is the path to the data
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        file_path = os.path.join(subdir, file)
        try:
            read_file(file_path) # This is where you read the files and push to mongo etc 
        except:
            continue
```

For the second part about reading Non-ISO extended-ASCII English text, there are some answers that might be helpful here: [File encoding from English text to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394723/file-encoding-from-english-text-to-utf-8)